# Pushing a List of objects

Tags: c#, list, object

I have a class as defined:

```
public class SavedScan
{
    public List<List<PointData>> SScan;
    public class PointData
    {
        public float amplitude;
    }
    public SavedScan()
    {
        SScan = new List<List<PointData>>();
    }
}
```

I then have a for loop, doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    List<SavedScan.PointData> tmp = new List<SavedScan.PointData>();
    SavedScan.PointData pointData = new SavedScan.PointData();

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        pointData.amplitude = 5.0;
        tmp.Add(pointData);
    }
    ss.SScan.Add(tmp);
}
```

The interesting thing is that when I run my debugger into `tmp.Add(pointData)`, I can see the `pointData` structure being read. However, the moment when it jumps out of the for loop and into `ss.SScan.Add(tmp)`, the `pointData.amplitude` value inside of `tmp` resets all to 0.

I can't figure out where I went wrong, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your instances of PointData **inside** the loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
{
    SavedScan.PointData pointData = new SavedScan.PointData();
    pointData.amplitude = 5.0;
    tmp.Add(pointData);
}
```

Comment: It works, but I do not understand why? Since after the loop `ss.SScan.Add(tmp)` is called immediately, there should not be anything to reset it back to 0.

Comment: Not sure how you're seeing 0 in there either...but you had a List<PointData> and you were adding the same instance into it ten times resulting in a List with only one entry.  By creating the instances inside the loop you are adding ten **different** instances that could all theoretically have their own distinct values.